# Wait for firestore data before calling view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, wait, subscribe

Whenever my app is launched I want to get the user data from firestore. So in my `app.component.ts` I have:

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, ..., private auth: AuthService, private firebaseServie: FirebaseService, private sessionData: SessiondataProvider) {

    //Here i call a function that I have in a service:
    if(this.sessionData.currentUser == undefined || this.sessionData.currentUser == null || this.sessionData.currentUser == ""){
      this.firebaseServie.setUserData(user.email);
    }
    //And then I start the ProfilePage View:
    this.rootPage = ProfilePage;
```

The service functipn `setUserData` calls an asynchronous request to firestore:

```
  setUserData(email) {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', email));
    this.userCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((item => {
      this.users = item;
      this.sessionData.currentUser = this.users[0].username;
    }));
  }
```

So the service function sets the global variable `currentUser`. In `app.component.ts` I want to be sure that the `currentUser` variable has been set, BEFORE launching the `ProfilePage` view. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from synchronous to async code with the help of RxJS Observable.

```
private asyncCode: Subject = new Subject<any>();
public asyncCode$: Observable = this.asyncCode.asObservable();

setUserData(email): void {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', email));
    this.userCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((item => {
      this.users = item;
      this.sessionData.currentUser = this.users[0].username;
      this.asyncCode.next(true);
    }));
  }

this.asyncCode$.subscribe((status)=>{
    this.rootPage = ProfilePage;
});
```

Comment: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.`

Comment: We can't return observable from subscribe. You can use subject

Comment: `Generic type 'Subject<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).` I get the same error for  `Oberservable`

Comment: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using SpinnerDialog. The `hide()` function of SpinnerDialog is called in the callback of the `subscribe`